# Possible to add ads to an already published app

Tags: android, ads, google-play, updates

All- I recently published an app on Google Play. I was wondering if it is possible to add ads in an update of my app, or if my app has to start with ads? (Much like you can't go from free to $0.99 for example). Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can always add ads to your published apps. Ads network has nothing to do with Google Play store. Hopefully your published app is free, otherwise your users will complain if you put ads in your paid apps.

Comment: It is free though I am sure my users will not be thrilled. I will look into it more, just wanted to make sure it was possible before actually setting up the accounts and all that stuff. Thanks for your answer/comment!

Comment: @azgolfer I really don't know what I need to do to get ads showing. I published it yesterday and added to the admob account. Didn't get much help on this. Your help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is azgolfers answer/comment but I just wanted to put in answer fromat to help other users know that my question has indeed been answered: "You can always add ads to your published apps. Ads network has nothing to do with Google Play store. Hopefully your published app is free, otherwise your users will complain if you put ads in your paid apps."

Comment: can you please elaborate.... I am having the same question and I don't want to release an update on play store just to show ads. Can you help me understand the process??

Answer (score 1):

***No its not possible to add new ads to your application without update your application and without this trick :D***

i am also a developer and publisher. 
day before yesterday admob disable my ads 1 of my favorite app.
i didn't remember my .jks file password which mean now i can't update my app.
 
i try to find a solution but didn't get anything.
 
but today while i m study about firebase real time database i get an idea which may also helps you.

***Here is a Plan*** :-

1st :- don't store your ad ids on string.xml because you can't update string 
2nd :- integrate ads only with code ( without layout )
3rd :- now where you put your ads id  
  mAdView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-8023878856256738/1741045606");

instead to put "ca-app-pub... your ad id " pass variable which connect to firebase database and then place your ads id on firebase db 

benefit of this trick :- 
if you want to add new ads just create new ads id and then just change in firebase db 
in app ads will automatically switch to your new ads  :)

[firebase realtime db video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=noB98K6A0TY)